# Box object and intendedly lose unnecessary/extra data?

Tags: c#, class, boxing, unboxing

How can I box an object (e.g. from type B to type A) and intendedly lose the extra data?

Example:

```
class A
{
    private string a;
    private DateTime time;

    public A(string a)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.time = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

//...

class B:A
{
    private string b;

    public B(string a, string b):base(a)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

//...

B b1 = new B("A", "B");

A a1 = (A)b; // Still has variable b
```

In this example I created a `B` and then boxed it into an `A`. The new `A` has still the `b` variable saved in it, because in reality it points to the `B` object.

I know I could create a new `A` with the old data from `B`, but (in this example) if I call the constructor of `A` with the old data of `B`, the time variable would be wrong.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "if I call the constructor of `A` with the old data of `B`, the time variable would be wrong."? The `time` is wrong on the instance of `B` or on the newly created instance of `A`? Your example doesn't contain a (copy)constructor of `A` initializing from other instance. And also this has nothing to do with boxing as that is casting a valuetype to `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You cannot change the type of an object in .NET. When it has been created, the type is fixed. That `B` object is a `B` when you made it, it's a `B` now, and it will continue to be a `B` until it gets collected.

If you want an `A`, you need to make an `A`.